# J2ME Record Store delete then insert Exception

Tags: java-me, recordstore

I am working on J2ME Record Stores and when i delete the contents successfully, and then i check it, it gives me the correct count which is zero. But when i insert again, it gives me error finding record exception, because it is inserting after the content that i had inserted before. It is inserting from 2 instead of 1.

Can anyone explain why is it happening that way?

Comment: Please post the code you're using to do this.  Also, please remember to accept answers that help you.  You do this with the little ("V") icons to the left of each answer.

Comment: The record id in a recordstore is unique and auto-incrementing, just like a primary key in an SQL database. When 1 has been used, it cannot be used again. (Unless you delete the recordstore and create it again).

Comment: i am sorry about not accepting the answer, Nate, thank you for your help! But the thing is i was not able to send the array using ObjectOutputStream. But anyway, i have done using looping through the array, but i wanted to it that way. And mr_lou, thank you for explaining, i just wanted to confirm, if it works that way. So that means, even if i delete 1, it would start off from 2. Is that what you are saying?

Comment: how do i close this comment. mr_lou's answer is good for me!!

Comment: You could ask @mr_lou to post his comment as an *answer*, and then *accept* it if he does.  Regarding your comment about the other question, I had suggested that you **not** use `ObjectOutputStream` at all for that purpose, explained why, and why looping through parameters did not mean that you had to make multiple `write()` calls.

Comment: mr_lou, please post your comment as an answer!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The record id in a recordstore is unique and auto-incrementing, just like a primary key in an SQL database. When 1 has been used, it cannot be used again. (Unless you delete the recordstore and create it again).